# Stash is rewriting my variables when outputting multiple entries - how to make them distinct?

Tags: stash, responsive-images

I'm using Stash for image replacement in my main column. {images} is a Matrix field.

In my body field, {image-1}, {image-2}, etc. are the image placeholders. My code looks like this ({images} is a Matrix field).

```
{images}
    {exp:stash:set name="image-{row_count}" type="snippet"}
        {exp:ce_img:single src="{image:url}"
     alt="{image:title}"}               
    {/exp:stash:set}
{/images}
{exp:stash:set name="content"}{body}{/exp:stash:set}
{exp:stash:get name="content" parse_vars="yes"}
```

This works fine, but then I need to run it again for the side column. I also run in to problems with my RSS feed - multiple entries on the page cause Stash to run over and over, but I'm not getting fresh results for each entry.

How do I make Stash run freshly each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{exp:stash:content}
  {images}
    {exp:stash:set name="image-{row_count}" type="snippet"}
        {exp:ce_img:single src="{image:url}"
     alt="{image:title}"}               
    {/exp:stash:set}
  {/images}
  {exp:stash:parse}{body}{/exp:stash:parse}
{/exp:stash:content}

{exp:stash:get name="content"}
```

Answer (score 0):

With what you already have set up: When you have multiple entries the stash 'image-{row_count}' variable can be overwritten each entry loop. Try adding in a reference to the entry id to distinguish the variables, like:

```
{images}
    {exp:stash:set name="image-{entry_id}-{row_count}" type="snippet"}
...
```

Comment: That won't work because {image-1}, {image-2}, etc. are the placeholders that get replaced with images. If they have the entry_id in them, they won't match up.